# Where's rootProject.ext in React Native project

Tags: android, react-native

In my React Native project, I need to set a few things like `minSdkVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, etc. In the `build.gradle` file, I see references to `rootProject.ext` section which appears to be a central location for settings. I ran a search in the project but couldn't find `rootProject.ext` anywhere except in this section of `build.gradle`. I can "cheat" and put actual values in there and it works but I'd like to know where `rootProject.ext` is. For example, where's the `compileSdkVersion` or `minSdkVersion` coming from in the following code?

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ingridtm"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

P.S. This is out of a regular React Native project -- targeting 0.63.4 -- that is created with `npx react-native init myproject`. So I changed nothing in `build.gradle` up to this point.

Answer (score 4):

You can place these root settings in your project-level `build.gradle` file (at `android/build.gradle`), in the `buildscript` section:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        ...
    }
```

Comment: A bit confusing starting this with "You can place these..." -- but this is actually the answer to OP's question. The top-level build.gradle contains these values. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!